# Use com.android.phone class via classloader

Tags: android, classloader

I need to use method from class com.android.phone.NetworkSetting to get in my application list of all available network operators. I tried to use ClassLoader but with no success.

```
private void loadNetworksList(){

    try{

        DexFile  df = new DexFile(new File("/system/app/Phone.apk"));
        ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader(); 
        Class NetworkSetting = df.loadClass("com.android.phone.NetworkSetting",cl);


        try{
            Method get = NetworkSetting.getMethod("loadNetworksList",  (Class[]) null);
            get.invoke(null, (Class[]) null);
        }catch( Exception e){
            riljLog("exception method");
        }

      }catch( IllegalArgumentException iAE ){
          throw iAE;
      }catch( Exception e ){
          riljLog("exception");
      }  
}
```

Comment: do you have any log message? where is point for problem?